# ERROR: CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import data into PostgreSQL with `NULL` values in Windows 7.

```
"Code1.2";"08";"ALCALA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";"";"2017/04/08";1 
"Code1.3";"46";"BARCELONA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";"";"2009/07/01";0
```

I don't want to import quotes `"data"` neither `""` values.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.TABLA1 ( 
    CODIGO text, 
    COD text, 
    MUNICIPIO text, 
    ESTADO text, 
    SITUACION text, 
    FECHA_INICIO date, 
    FECHA_FIN date, 
    CONTADOR numeric
);
```

If I import data with the following I can handle `NULL` values, but I have the  `""` in the data:

```
COPY public.TABLA1 (
    CODIGO, 
    COD, 
    MUNICIPIO, 
    ESTADO, 
    SITUACION, 
    FECHA_INICIO, 
    FECHA_FIN, 
    CONTADOR
) 
FROM 'C:\DATA\ORIGEN\fichero_prueba.csv' 
WITH (DELIMITER ';', NULL '""');

| CODIGO    | COD  | MUNICIPIO | ESTADO          |SITUACION    |FECHA_INICIO|...
| --------- | ---- | --------- | ----------------|-------------|------------|...
| "Code1.2" | "08" |"ALCALA"   |"ACTIVO SERVICIO"|"EN SERVICIO"|[null]      |...
| "Code1.3" | "46" |"BARCELONA"|"ACTIVO SERVICIO"|"EN SERVICIO"|[null]      |...
 ...
```

On the other hand If I import the data with the following, trying to leave the quotation marks out:

```
COPY public.TABLA1 ( 
    CODIGO,
    COD,
    MUNICIPIO,
    ESTADO,
    SITUACION,
    FECHA_INICIO,
    FECHA_FIN,
    CONTADOR
)
FROM 'C:\DATA\ORIGEN\fichero_prueba.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV QUOTE '"' NULL '""';
```

> **ERROR:** CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification

And not using `NULL`:

```
COPY public.TABLA1 (
    CODIGO,
    COD,
    MUNICIPIO,
    ESTADO,
    SITUACION,
    FECHA_INICIO,
    FECHA_FIN,
    CONTADOR
)
FROM 'C:\DATA\ORIGEN\fichero_prueba.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV QUOTE '"';
```

> **ERROR:**  invalid input syntax for type date: «»

How can I import the data without the `""` and handle `NULL` values in date types?

Comment: Por favor, habla en engles si posible.  Este website esta usando engles y no español.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I translated it

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first is what you want, you're converting empty strings to `NULL` and the quotation marks are showing because those values are, in fact, strings. If that's not what you want then try to thoroughly explain the expected behavior.

Comment: @Oxfist I don't think so, because I had changed data manually (to make a test) and use it without the initial quotes and in the database I can see my text columns without quotes.

Comment: @alisson I noticed that in the first one you didn't add `QUOTE '"'` to the `COPY` statement, maybe try that.

Comment: @Oxfist If I do that I have this error: CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL

Comment: @alisson what version of PostgreSQL are you running? I think you can just remove `CSV`, since from what I read in the docs that's and old syntax.

Comment: @Oxfist PosgreSQL 9.6 and Pgadmin 4v1.. The only thing that works is creating date columns as text...so far.

Comment: @alisson I'm reproducing your problem on my db so I can check for options, just a question, can you modify the original file? The intended behavior in Postgres is that you cannot specify `NULL '""'` while in CSV mode, and in order to add `QUOTE` you *have* to be in CSV mode.

Comment: @Oxfist I extract the original file from ftp server.. and the original file is .dat format and the only thing I can do is to change the extension from '.dat' to '.csv'

Answer (score 1):

From one of your answers in the comments I assume you have access to the file (since you can change the extension from `.dat` to `.csv`) so I'd recommend opening the file in Excel (or any equivalent) and removing the quotes from the `FECHA_INICIO` column, so that instead of:

```
"Code1.2";"08";"ALCALA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";"";"2017/04/08";1 
"Code1.3";"46";"BARCELONA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";"";"2009/07/01";0
```

You'd have:

```
"Code1.2";"08";"ALCALA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";;"2017/04/08";1 
"Code1.3";"46";"BARCELONA";"ACTIVO SERVICIO";"EN SERVICIO";;"2009/07/01";0
```

If you can do this then the following will insert the data to the table without the double quotes and with `NULL` in the `FECHA_INICIO` column:

```
COPY public.TABLA1 (
    CODIGO, 
    COD, 
    MUNICIPIO, 
    ESTADO, 
    SITUACION, 
    FECHA_INICIO, 
    FECHA_FIN, 
    CONTADOR
) 
FROM 'C:\DATA\ORIGEN\fichero_prueba.csv' 
WITH CSV DELIMITER ';' QUOTE '"';
```

Comment: I cannot open it in excel because it has more than 4.000.000 rows and the limit in excel is 1.000.000. I change the extension using powershell.

Comment: @alisson from what I gathered reading the docs I think your solution is to modify the original file, e.g. you could use Vim or any text editor to replace `"";` for `;`, because `QUOTE '"'` and `NULL '""'`  will definitely not work together in CSV mode, and to use `QUOTE` you *have* to be in CSV mode.

Comment: Furthermore, if you're confident that you won't find double quotes that need to be escaped, you could just use a text editor to remove every single double quote and I'm sure you'll get the result you want.